# How can Jack-Jack have so many powers compared to the rest of the kids of his age?

Tags: incredibles-2

I know Edna Marie told Mr. Incredible in *Incredibles 2* that children at a young age have the  potential to have more than one power, but she also said that his child has a lot of them.

I want to know, what is the reason behind him having so many powers? I know he is the son of Mr. Incredible but then his other kids should have many powers too.

Comment: "then his other kids should have many powers too." Why? Random genetic mutations cause all kinds of things. Plenty of families where kids have completely different abilities, or where one kid is significantly more talented than the others.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

So Brad Bird has explained this one quite succinctly;

He's quoted to say:

> "What interests me is the idea of having a family, having there be a
>   reason to hide the powers," Bird said. "And once I had that insight
>   into what I wanted to do, I picked the powers based on who they were
>   in the family. And so men are always expected to be strong, so I had
>   Bob have super strength. Women, mothers are always pulled in a million
>   different directions, so I had her be elastic. Teenagers are insecure
>   and defensive, so I had Violet have force fields and invisibility.
>   Ten-year-olds are energy balls that can't be stopped. And babies are
>   unknown, maybe they have no powers, maybe they have all powers, we
>   don't know.
>
> "So, that's what Jack-Jack was, he was seemingly the first normal one
>   in the family and then at the end of Incredibles you find out that
>   he's the wild card, and that he's sort of the Swiss army knife of
>   powers. And that to me reminds me of the way babies can grasp
>   languages really easily and adopt them easily."

https://comicbook.com/movies/2018/04/15/why-incredibles-have-specific-powers-pixar-brad-bird/

These traditional societal values for each family member have been transposed onto the members of the Incredibles family and, really, with this in mind, the most relevant "power" for Jack-Jack to have, as a baby in a family where the members *are* their powers, is *all* powers. Bird mentions how babies/children can adopt many languages, but babies moods can quickly change, they can get up to mischief, and they can be troublemakers exactly when you don't want them to. Jack-Jack embodies all of this, and who's to say his powers won't become more refined and singular as he ages, but as far as The Incredibles 1 & 2 goes, this is how *his* powers are expressed.

From the filmmakers conceptual viewpoint, this is how Jack-Jack's powers were decided, however as for a more actual and realistic reasoning, we can't know. The origin of 'Supers' never was explained as far as I remember the films, and so thus far we don't know if this is caused by genetic changes as per Marvel's X-Men, or simple magic, or an aeons-old curse, or some other reason.

Welcome to the community, by the way!

Comment: Wow, I should try thinking more in details from  now own. Thanks, its a pleasure to be here.